# Changing product picture

Tags: php, sql, image

```
<?php
    $Name=$_POST['txtName'];
    $Desc=$_POST['txtDesc'];
    $path1 = $_FILES["txtFile"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["txtFile"]["tmp_name"],"../Products/"  .$_FILES["txtFile"]["name"]);
    //** Establish Connection with MYSQL
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    // Select Database
    mysql_select_db("jmmc", $con);
    // Specify the query to Update Record
    $sql = "Update admin_category set CategoryName='".$Name."',Description='".$Desc."',Image='".$path1."' where CategoryId=".$Id."";
    // Execute query
    mysql_query($sql,$con);
    // Close The Connection
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: where is your question or issue or any related console error..?

Comment: i want to update the current product image with a new image

Comment: sorry guys im new to php and sql

Comment: Apart that you're using `mysql_` which is already deprecated, and your code subjected to SQL injection, what is the problem? You already mention your intention, but what's wrong with  the code? Please explain the issue clearly by [editiing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32391355/edit) the post.

Comment: the image is not uploaded to the folder i put and the image is not shown in the product list

Answer (score 0):

Send me error you are getting from code.
Check your file location path that is not true

or

may be you did not create folder Product and check your database make confirm you have right column names

Check Your all Variables like $Id,$Name,$Desc have a proper values 
like

(where CategoryId=".$Id."")

you need to define enctype,method type(get or post) in form and make  html like this:

```
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="txtFile" >
  <input type="hidden" name="txtDesc" value="aaaaa"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="txtName" value="naveed"> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit_button">
  </form>
```

You need to define PHP code in isset statement like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
 $fileName = $_FILES["txtFile"] ["name"];
if (isset($fileName)) {
 $Name=$_POST['txtName'];
 $Desc=$_POST['txtDesc'];
 $path1 = $_FILES["txtFile"]["name"];
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["txtFile"]["tmp_name"],"../Products/"  .$_FILES["txtFile"]["name"]);
 //** Establish Connection with MYSQL
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
  // Select Database   
  mysql_select_db("stackoverflow", $con); 
 // Specify the query to Update Record


$sql = "Update admin_category set CategoryName='".$Name."',Description='".$Desc."',Image='".$path1."' where CategoryId=".$Id."";

 // Execute query

 mysql_query($sql,$con);

 // Close The Connection

 mysql_close($con);
 }

   }
 ?>
```